# What's the best practice for api authentication for B2B?

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport, b2b

I've an API built on laravel and I need to provide API access to a third party application. What is the best way to achieve this? I'm using Laravel Passport. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the third party application doesn't involve authentication, you can consider generate a client and create a **Personal Access Token** for the third party application.

In addition, protect the routes with middleware that perform access token verification and scope verification to prevent unauthorized access.

Refer documentation below:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#creating-a-personal-access-client

Middleware protection:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#via-middleware

Hope it helps.

Comment: in my case the application involves in authentication.